# Can't use variable in DateTime's modify() function. I'm getting an error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string

Tags: php, date, time, date-math

I managed to dynamically load and compare several time values in PHP.

Right now I am stuck here:

```
$additional_time = $entry_start->diff($compare_from_timeformat);
$additional_time ->format("H:i");
$avaliabletime->modify('+1 hours');
```

I want to replace the `+1` with `$avaliabletime` but if i try something like this:

```
$avaliabletime->modify('+'.$additional_time.' hours');
```

I get this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string

So I got 2 questions now.

1. is there a way to use a variable with the modify part ?
2. can I also add minutes in the same string ? for example `$avaliabletime->modify('+01:45 hours');` ?

Comment: In coding `I am done`  is not acceptable. If you follow the same mindset , you will not be able to handle **Complex Projects** for sure! Please be optimistic.

Comment: with I am almost done I meant that I am almost finished, sry, I may have sounded like i gave up, but I didn't. I am very much aware of all the great pro's being active here who knows stuff better than I do :))

Answer (score 4):

`$additional_time` is a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object, not a `DateTime` object or string. To modify your DateTime object by the amount that `DateInterval` represents use [`DateTime::add()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php):

```
$additional_time = $entry_start->diff($compare_from_timeformat);
$avaliabletime->add($additional_time);
```

If you want to add additional time *then* you can use `DateTime::modify()`:

```
$additional_time = $entry_start->diff($compare_from_timeformat);
$avaliabletime->add($additional_time);
$avaliabletime->modify('+45 minutes');
```

Comment: Thank you John !

No the Minutes are present in $avaliabletime i.e.' 01:30'.
So if I use $avaliabletime->add($additional_time); that would also include the minutes right? 

If so i wouldnt need the -> modify part